# Flutter / Dart Convert Int to Enum

Tags: enums, dart, flutter

Is there a simple way to convert an integer value to enum? I want to retrieve an integer value from shared preference and convert it to an enum type.

My enum is:

```
enum ThemeColor { red, gree, blue, orange, pink, white, black };
```

I want to easily convert an integer to an enum:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
ThemeColor c = ThemeColor.convert(prefs.getInt('theme_color')); // something like that
```

Comment: How did you add enum in the SharedPrefs. Could you please guide me a bit.

Comment: @Pawan being `status` an `enum`, you can `status.index` to get the int value

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
int idx = 2;
print(ThemeColor.values[idx]);
```

should give you

```
ThemeColor.blue
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use:

```
ThemeColor.red.index
```

should give you

```
0
```

Answer (score 14):

In Dart 2.17, you can use enhanced enums with values (which could have a different value to your index). Make sure you use the correct one for your needs.  You can also define your own getter on your enum.

```
//returns Foo.one
print(Foo.values.firstWhere((x) => x.value == 1));
  
//returns Foo.two
print(Foo.values[1]);
  
//returns Foo.one
print(Foo.getByValue(1));

enum Foo {
  one(1),
  two(2);

  const Foo(this.value);
  final num value;
  
  static Foo getByValue(num i){
    return Foo.values.firstWhere((x) => x.value == i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Warning, make sure you handle non-existent integer with a try/catch.

```dart
/// Shows what to do when creating an enum value from a integer value

enum ThemeColor { red, green,}


void main() {
  
  try {
    final nonExistent = ThemeColor.values[3];
    print("Non existent enum is $nonExistent");

  }
  catch(e) {
    print("Non existent enum thrown"); 
  }
}

// Non existent enum thrown
```

The dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=4e99d3f578311288842a0ab5e069797e

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with enhanced enums, plus:

- More propertie(s) attached to enum values
- Factory constructor
- Fallback value in constructor
- Implementation of the Comparable interface
- Overload of comparison operator(s)
- Conversion to map

Tested on Dart 2.19.6.

```
enum AuthLevel implements Comparable<AuthLevel> {
  guest(1, 'Guest'),
  user(2, 'Registered user'),
  admin(5, 'Administrator'),
  developer(9, 'Developer');

  final int level;
  final String desc;

  const AuthLevel(this.level, this.desc);

  // Conversion from int
  factory AuthLevel.fromInt(int level) =>
      values.firstWhere((value) => value.level == level, orElse: () => guest);

  // Conversion to int
  int get toInt => level;

  @override
  int compareTo(AuthLevel other) => level - other.level;

  // Comparison operator(s)
  bool operator >=(AuthLevel other) => level >= other.level;
  // ... possibly add more

  @override
  String toString() => '{level: $level, desc: $desc}';

  // Conversion to map
  Map<int, String> toMap() =>
      {for (var value in AuthLevel.values) value.level: value.desc};
}
```