# Dart: How to cast enum to int?

Tags: dart

How to cast enum value to integer value in Dart?

```
enum ETabs { eTabRed, eTabGreen, eTabBlue }

int tabIndex = 0;

tabIndex = ETabs.eTabRed; // ERROR!
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190035/flutter-dart-convert-int-to-enum

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tabIndex = ETabs.eTabRed.index;
```

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly define index value? For example, if I wanted the `eTabRed` value to hold -3 or -4?