# How to assign raw value to enum in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

In Swift, you can easily assign raw value to enum, eg:

```swift
enum Game: Int {
    case lol = 1
    case dnf = 2
    case dota = 3
}
```

However, you can't assign raw value to enum in Dart:

```dart
enum Game {
  lol = 1,
  dnf = 2,
  dota = 3,
}
```

It's showed error and you can only use the simplest enum:

```dart
enum Game {
  lol,
  dnf,
  dota,
}
```

It's really let me down.

Any way assign raw value to Dart's enum like Swift?

Comment: idk why a VERY simple feature like this is not built already in dart, even with enhanced enum it's so weird and tricky to achieve the same result as you can do in C#, java, swift and many others.... dart really need to improve their enums...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an upcoming feature in Dart known as enhanced enums, and it allows for enum declarations with many of the features known from classes. For example:

```dart
enum Game {
    lol,
    dnf,
    dota;
  int get intValue => index + 1;
}
```

The feature is not yet released (and note that several things are not yet working), but experiments with it can be performed with a suitably fresh version of the tools by passing `--enable-experiment=enhanced-enums`.

The outcome is that an enum value of type `Game` will have a getter `intValue` that returns the `int` values mentioned in the question, so `print(myGame.intValue)` will print 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 18):

`Dart 2.17` support enhanced enum

```
enum Game {
  lol(1),
  dnf(2),
  dota(3);
  
  const Game(this.value);
  final int value;
}
```

Use it like:

```
void main() {
  const game = Game.lol;
  print(game.value); // 1
}
```

Comment: If it is desired to obtain the enum from the value, you can add a factory constructor like this:
factory Game.fromValue(int value) {
  return Game.values.firstWhere((x) => x.value == value);
}
This is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924638/7927429

Answer (score 4):

You can use enum extensions for example

```
enum EnumAction { subtract, add }

extension EnumActionExtension on EnumAction {
  String get name {
    switch (this) {
      case EnumAction.add:
        return 'add';
      case EnumAction.subtract:
        return 'subtract';
    }
  }
}
```

In your case you would return an int and an int value. Enums also have int values assigned to them by default, their respective index. You could call Game.lol.index and it would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

To get an int value, simply pass an enum to the enumGame function.

```
enum EnumGame { lol, dnf, dota }
```

> 

```
enumGame(EnumGame enumGame) {
  switch (enumGame) {
    case EnumGame.lol:
      return 1;
    case EnumGame.dnf:
      return 2;
    case EnumGame.dota:
      return 3;
    default:
      return -1;
  }
}
```